# Why is "being created" considered an imperfection?

Tags: nature-of-god, perfection, divinity

I've seen the uncreated God contrasted many times to the created angels, Satan, and humans, and etc. Being created is counted against the latter category as a mark of imperfection which God does not bear.

However I don't really see why being created is an imperfection.  Surely something can be created and be created perfectly, right?  To become perfect?

Is there a way to understand this through the bigger picture of what perfection is?  Or is this something that must be understood on its own?

Comment: "Being created is counted against the latter category as a mark of imperfection which God does not bear." Who says this? I don't really remember seeing Christians say this; instead most Christians say that the creation was perfect, until the fall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being created doesn't affect perfection as much as impassability. The doctrine of impassability states that God cannot change- that he is the same yesterday, today, and tomorrow. If God (or Jesus) were created then he has changed - he went from not existing to existing.

The tie in between perfection and impassability is this: if God changes, then it sets up a situation where God is not perfect. If he changed, he would, it is assumed, move to being 'perfect' from a state that was necessarily 'less than perfect.' That previous state, adherents of impassability maintain, is inconsistent with the nature of God's perfection, hence it cannot be.

Comment: Ah it makes sense that being created is at odds with being unchanging :)

Comment: Can you define the words "create" and "exist"? There is room for confusion as they stand.
"Cannot change" does not imply did not change".
This answer is contradicted by the invitation of the Savior to become perfect--proving that now-perfect beings may indeed have changed in the past.

Comment: @pygosceles affable Geek passed away  February 14, 2015.      Don’t  expect a reply.  He was a great contributor here!

Answer (score 2):

Being created is not what makes something imperfect. Creation was created perfect by a perfect God:

> And God saw everything that He had made, and behold, it was very good (suitable, pleasant) and **He approved it completely**. And there was evening and there was morning, a sixth day.

[Genesis 1:31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201:31&version=AMP)

If God approves it *completely*, it must be perfect.

But then Adam and Eve *choose* a path which made them imperfect. God warned them:

> But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil and blessing and calamity you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die.

[Genesis 2:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202:17&version=AMP)

but they went ahead anyway:

> And when the woman saw that the tree was good (suitable, pleasant) for food and that it was delightful to look at, and a tree to be desired in order to make one wise, she took of its fruit and ate; and she gave some also to her husband, and he ate.

[Genesis 3:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:6&version=AMP)

Summary: their *choice* made them imperfect, *after* they were created.

Comment: I've heard it said "Angels cannot be perfect because they were created"; is this something valid to say, or does it have no grounds?

Comment: @JustinL.: I'm not aware of any Biblical verse stating that. The only thing that is clear to me is that some angels are not perfect (fallen). My *guess* is that the others (not fallen) are perfect - otherwise they could not [worship God in heaven](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%205:11&version=AMP).

Answer (score 0):

The word "perfect" literally means "[thoroughly made, completely done](https://www.google.com/search?q=perfect%20word%20origin)". In that sense even a creation can certainly be called "perfect" so long as its "being made" is so thorough that nothing remains to be done. However, that is not the word God used towards the original creation, He used the terms "good" and "very good" (Genesis 1:31). This might suggest to the reader that even after the initial Creation, something remains to be done.

Jesus Christ commands us, mortal men and women, to be perfect, "even as [our] Father in heaven is perfect" (Matthew 5:48). Therefore there is no contradiction between being a so-called "created" being and eventually being perfect through the power of Christ.
This commandment can be seen as the consummation of Creation: That by the redeeming and enabling power of the Atonement of Jesus Christ, we can become free from our sins and empowered to allow Christ to finish our creation, until we are perfect in Him by His grace.